# Getting bad request trying to pass usermetadata on VSI create

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The JSON payload basically works creating a VSI if I don't pass in the userData stanza.

I am getting RCV 400 MSG "Bad Request", with error "{"error":"Bad request","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_WebService_BadRequest"}'

The URL is  https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest with a POS method

The JSON payload is:

{
       "parameters" :
     [
              { "hostname" : "garycs-test-userdata-02",
                "domain" : "sl.cloud9.ibm.com",
                "startCpus": 2,
                    "maxMemory": 2,
                "hourlyBillingFlag" : "true",
                "operatingSystemReferenceCode" : "CENTOS_7_64",

```
                "localDiskFlag" : false,

        "userData" : [
            {
                "value" : "{"dataclass":"IBMConfidential"}",
                "type: : {
                            "name" : "User Data",
                            "keyname" : "USER_DATA"
                            }
            }
          ],

            "networkComponents" : [
               {
             "maxSpeed" : 1000
           }
             ],
                 "privateNetworkOnlyFlag" : true,

      "primaryBackendNetworkComponent" : {
          "networkVlan" : {
            "id": 2298951
        }

       },



            "datacenter" : {
           "name" : "dal13"
             }
           }
         ]
}
```

What is wrong with the userData stanza?

Comment: I saw an error in the userData structure and corrected it to "userData" : [
                {
                    "value" : "{"dataclass":"IBMConfidential"}",
                    "type" : {
                                "name" : "User Data",
                                "keyname" : "USER_DATA"
                                }
                }
              ],       but still get the error

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it´s failing is because “value” attribute needs a single string value contained, as you are sending several double quotation marks then json structure is broken, and throws an exception message error for this reason when you sent the request

I suggest trying to use simple quote mark, or scape mark in order to replace the double quote mark into string value, like the following examples:

```
"userData": [
        {
          "value": "{'dataclass':'IBMConfidential'}",
           "type": {
            "name": "User Data",
            "keyname": "USER_DATA"
          }
        }
      ],
```

Or:

```
"userData": [
        {
          "value": "{\"dataclass\":\"IBMConfidential\"}",
           "type": {
            "name": "User Data",
            "keyname": "USER_DATA"
          }
        }
      ],
```

For further reference, see the following:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject/

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getUserMetadata/

Comment: No problem, glad to help.